# Why is the reaction force same in magnitude to the action force in Newton's third law of motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

In Newton's $3$rd law of motion, it states that

> All forces between two objects exist in equal magnitude and opposite direction

How did Newton knew exactly that the "reaction" force will be equal in magnitude to the "action" force? What would happen if the "reaction" force ,say, half the "action" force?

For example, if I push a small rock with my fingers and the rock moves, the rock is also pushing on my fingers with the same amount of force (and opposite the direction) but because of the difference in mass, the rock is the one moving.

But how do we know for sure that the rock is also pushing on my fingers with the **same amount** of force and not half of it (or a quarter)? What would happen if the rock is pushing on my fingers half of the force I'm pushing on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but because of the difference in mass, the rock is the one moving.

Actually, *both* you and the rock are moving. The difference in mass just causes the rock to move faster - but you move as well (this is according to Newton's 2nd law).

> how do we know for sure that the rock is also pushing on my fingers with the same amount of force and not half of it (or a quarter)?

We know that from many, many, many, many experiments. It is an emperical law, so not a law you can prove but a law you can test until you trust it to always hold true. Similarly to how you trust in, say, gravity.

As to the consequence if Newton's 3rd law wasn't a thing: basically, if any applied force wouldn't be countered by an equal but opposite reaction force, then internal forces would not balance out and you would theoretically be able to pull yourself up by the hair.

Comment: How is it that if Newton's 3rd law wasn't true then internal forces wouldn't balance out? I thought Newton's 3rd law talks about the interaction between 2 bodies and not internal forces.

Comment: @Mohammadmuazzamali You can consider yourself and the stone as two distinct bodies. But you consist of several parts, limbs, particles, molecules. So does the stone. Such internal particles do interact and exert forces on each other, exchange momentum, energy etc. Any force by one particle on another is balanced out by an equal force from that other particle which causes the net inertal force to be zero. What you define as one body - as a system - is up to you precisely because any such internal interactions cancel out and only external influence is important.

Comment: So what would happen if the rock is pushing my fingers half (or some other fraction of) the force my fingers pushing on it? I believe that this will violate the Newton's third law, but I still can't imagine how things would go.

Comment: @Mohammadmuazzamali The entire stone would fall apart, I suppose, since all particles would eventually move at different speeds and would not settle and remain coherent (momentum conservation would be violated).

Answer (score 2):

To add to Steeven's answer:

The action-reaction principle of Newton's third law leads to the conservation of momentum. If the action-reaction principle were not true, then neither would the law of conservation of momentum be true.

And we know that the law of conservation of momentum always holds true.

Comment: We know that the law of conservation of momentum holds true from all the experiments? or can it be proven in some way? Sorry, I'm quite new to this.

Comment: @Mohammadmuazzamali The momentum conservation law can be derived from Newton's 3rd law, but Newton's 3rd law is an emperical/experimental/observed law. (Or the other way around).